# How to solve the following differential equation? If not, state why?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$x'(t)=(x-1)^2$$

My professor said that we can't solve the equation and find a function that satisfies the differential equation. I don't really get what he means.

What I've done so far is
$$ \frac{dx}{dt}= (x-1)^2 $$

$$ \int dx = \int(x-1)^2dt$$

$$ x= \frac{(-2t-1)+((2t+1)^2-4t(t+C))^\frac{1}{2}}{-2t}$$

OR $$x= \frac{(-2t-1)-((2t+1)^2-4t(t+C))^\frac{1}{2}}{-2t}$$

Is it correct? If not, do you think I can solve it or find a function that satisfies the DE?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Impressive formatting for someone just starting! That was unhelpful of your professor! A standard approach works here. Get everything with $x$ on one side and everything with $t$ on the other. So your first line was correct: writing $x'(t)$ as $\frac{dx}{dt}$, but then dvide both sides by $(x-1)^2$ and it is easy from then on.

Comment: You are integrating the function of x with respect to t.

Comment: You should check again your sources, the contested statement in this form is wrong. What does not exist is a general differentiable solution with the whole of $\Bbb R$ as domain, as except for the constant solution $x=1$ every other solution has a pole at a finite time.

Comment: It is not clear to me how you got from the integral equation to the expressions for $x$. But one thing you certainly should have done was check your solutions in the original equations. When you differentiate $x$ with respect to $t$, do you get $(x-1)^2$?

Answer (score 2):

**Wrong**. Start from
$$\cdots = \int\frac{dx}{(x-1)^2} = \int dt = \cdots$$

Comment: In order to decide by $(x-1)^2$ you must know that $x-1 \neq 0 \forall t\in \mathbb{R}$. I think that's the reason why the professor said it's unsolvable!!!

Comment: @AnastassisKapetanakis : This makes no sense. That a solution method fails (even if only in a specific case) does not imply that no solution exists. Treat the problem, totally exaggerating its complexity, as a Riccati equation with the ansatz $x-1=-\frac{u'}{u}$, then $u''=0$ results and $$x(t)=1-\frac{A}{Ax+B}$$ parametrizes all solutions, the constant solution corresponds to the totally non-singular case $(A,B)=(0,1)$.

Comment: @LutzL Sorry I didn't meant mean to say that this equation is unsolvable. I didn't put that right! I just wanted to say that the common way that is used in this answer to solve this ODE is completely wrong and I am asking myself: Why this answer already has 2 upvotes? It's mathematically wrong because it ignores the basic requirement for division: the denominator must be non-zero! Am I wrong here?

Comment: @AnastassisKapetanakis : The usual way is to look at the equation and see that it is autonomous and that $x=1$ is a root of the right side. So the constant function $x(t)=1$ is a solution, and (by uniqueness, smooth rhs) no other solution takes anywhere the value $1$. Thus you are free to perform this division to find a formula for any of these other solutions. :: Thus while incomplete, this hint gives a totally correct solution method, called "separation of variables".

Answer (score 2):

We have $(-\frac 1 {x-1})'(t)=1$ so $-\frac 1 {x-1} =t+c$ for some constant $c$. This gives $x(t)=1-\frac 1 {t+c}$. You can verify that this is indeed a solution of the given DE on $\mathbb R \setminus \{-c\}$.

Besides $x=1$ is  a solution on the entire real line.

Comment: There is no ODE solution that has a split domain. This functional expression is either a solution on $(-\infty,-c)$ or a solution on $(-c,\infty)$, depending on where the initial point is located.

Comment: Still, a solution to an ODE always has an interval as domain, even if the connection between integration constant and initial value is not made. So one functional expression gives here two separate solutions.

Comment: That is not the problem, the singularity here is that the non-constant solutions leave the domain $\Bbb R^2$, that is diverge to infinity, in finite time. There is no continuation after that, even if the functional expression suggests some kind of passing from $+\infty$ to $-\infty$ through some "underworld".